Finding inverse to inner automorphism (Humphreys' Lie Algebra book)
This is basically an algebra question. In Humphreys' book on Lie algebras he states that one can find the inverse to $\exp \delta$, where $\delta$ is a nilpotent derivation - say $\delta^k=0$, by setting $\exp \delta = 1 + \eta$, giving the inverse as $1 - \eta + \eta^2 - \eta^3 + \cdots \pm \eta^{k-1}$. My question is how does he derive this from the Taylor polynomial expansion of $\exp \delta$? Is he doing something else?

It's just a geometric series. But also you can just take $\exp (-\delta)$.

Ah, this is emberrasing. You're saying that $\exp \delta = 1+\eta \Rightarrow \frac{\exp \delta}{1 + \eta} = 1$ (as $1+\eta \neq 0$), then expand out $(1+\eta)^{-1}$ up to order $k-1$, right?

Yes, that's right.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Just to take this off the "unanswered" list, Qiaochu Yuan writes in a comment,
"It's just a geometric series. But also you can just take $\exp(-\delta)$."
and OP raynea confirms,
"$\exp\delta = 1+\eta \implies \frac{\exp \delta}{1+\eta} = 1$ (as $1+\eta \neq 0$), then expand out $(1+\eta)^{-1}$ up to order $k-1$"
